# how to make an additional condition in an excel array formula

Tags: excel, vba

So I know this isnt exactly a programming question, but it does affect my underlying vba... I cant figure out what I should do.

How do I modify this excel formula to accept an additional condition for each value is either >0 or <0

Current formula is this:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(I13:M13),I13:M13))}
```

where each vlaue I13 through M13 is a number or an error

This is what I tried but it doesnt work:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(I13:M13), ">"&0),I13:M13))}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd go with Doug's AVERAGEIF but FWIW the syntax would be like this for an array formula `=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(I13:M13),IF(I13:M13>0,I13:M13)))` - you can't use AND because AND returns a single value not an array

Comment: @barryhoudini, here's the XL2003 version I came up with: `=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(I13:M13)*(I13:M13<0)>0,I13:M13))`, with inspiration from [this DDOE post](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/03/23/maxif-and-minif-with-multiple-variables/).

Comment: @Doug Glancy, yep, there are several ways for Excel 2003 - I think using multiple IFs is arguably slightly faster than multiplying but I doubt that the difference is significant - another way would be `=SUMIF()/COUNTIF` avoiding array entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually just use `AVERAGEIF` - in Excel 2007 or higher, as it disregards non-numeric values. Here it is for values less that zero:

```
=AVERAGEIF(I13:M13,"<0")
```

Comment: Glad to help. If this, or any other answer, works for you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.